# Android player continues callbacks , buffering

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a MediaPlayer to play some sound from an online `mp3` file in my app.

However, even after the play completes, I'm getting lines and lines of callsbacks and buffering in the console.

```
10-24 08:08:48.467  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:48.467  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:49.468  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:49.468  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:49.468  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:49.468  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:50.469  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:50.469  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:50.469  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:50.469  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:51.470  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:51.470  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:51.470  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:51.470  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:52.471  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:52.471  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:52.471  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:52.471  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:53.472  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:53.472  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:53.472  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:53.472  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:54.473  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:54.473  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:54.473  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:54.473  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:55.473  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:55.473  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:55.473  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:55.473  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:56.474  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
10-24 08:08:56.474  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ buffering 100
10-24 08:08:56.474  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
10-24 08:08:56.474  19221-19233/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
10-24 08:08:57.475  19221-19232/com.myapp V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
```

I tried calling `stop()` on the player but this just prevents the player from ever playing properly.

What can I do?

Comment: any insights on that? I have the same now ^^

Comment: ok, I solved it for my case I think: I stupidly forgot to set the setOnPreparedListener() o_O

Comment: @JoergSimon I have setOnprepareListener setted and I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it out? I'm experiencing this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that nothing else is running in the background (like Pandora)?

I found your question because my droid was producing the same logcat messages. Then I realized my Pandora app was paused, after ending the app the messages stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I found this in my case too.

Try to add a OnCompletionListener.

`voicePlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.reset();
    }
});`